# What is most efficient way to reverse a string in .net?

Tags: .net, string

I can find no `String.Reverse()` in .net that actually returns a string. (Any reason why there is none?) What would the most efficient code (least temp objects created etc) for reversing a string in .net be?

Comment: In retrospect, I think I see the answer: the reason there is none, is that it is ambiguous what string.Reverse should do, and therefore a source of surprises and bugs:
should it return you all the UTF-16 codepoints of your string in reverse order? Or the UTF-32 codepoints? What about combining marks and ordering? Should it return you unicode text which should visually look like the original string but reversed? Which canonical representation of that?

Answer (score 1):

With .NET 4.5 (maybe earlier, I dunno), the framework ships with an extension method to the `String` class named `Reverse`.

`Reverse()` returns an `IEnumerable<Char>`, which is directly assignable to a `String`.

So this should work:

```
string one = "kayak";
string two = (string)(one.Reverse());
```

Comment: The built in string Reverse was added for .net 3.5.  At the Same time MS snuck in REVERSE string into SQL server for SQL Server 2008 and later.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static string ReverseString(string s)
{
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return new string(arr);
}
```